Can I find out wheter a lock _can_ be acquired in PostgreSQL
Is it possible to find out whether, say ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT will acquire a lock immediately, or will have to wait on a different session?

Are going to use NOT VALID or not? Also check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES

Even if you could find that out, it'll just tell you that a moment ago you could have acquired the lock. Then when you try to actually acquire it in the next step, the situation may already have changed.

I think that the best solution is to try and see. For that purpose, set lock_timeout to 1 millisecond, so that the ALTER TABLE statement fails if it cannot acquire a lock immediately:
BEGIN;  -- start transaction

SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 1;  -- only for this transaction

ALTER TABLE ...

COMMIT;  -- will rollback if there was an error

